# GridView: GridView with different cells sizes and layout,

Tags: android

Hi I need a gridview which have 2 different layout in grid cells according to grid cell type.here is I am giving the example scrren drawn on paper.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` that have set `SpanSizeLookup`. So it will be as follows:

```
int fullSpanSize = 3;
int normalSpanSize = 1;

GridLayoutManager layout = new GridLayoutManager(context, fullSpanSize);
layout.setSpaneSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return position == 3 ? fullSpanSize : normalSpanSize;
    }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **StaggeredGridLayoutManager**, then in Adapter override **getItemViewType(int position)** method to return different viewTypes based on your cell/data type so when you inflate the items in **onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType)** you can chose a different layout for the cell based on viewType.